# Time complexity of String.contains()

Tags: string, algorithm, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of String.contains();
lets say n is the length of the string that is compared against another string of length k.

Comment: It isn't specified. A *naive* implementation would be `O(n*k)`, but there are faster algorithm, and which one is used isn't stated in the Javadoc,

Answer (score 5):

There is no answer without knowing the actual implementation of the String.contains() that you're interested in; or what algorithm you intend to use.

A completely naive implementation might take `(n+1-k)*k`comparisons to decide that a given string of length `n` does not contain a particular substring of length `k`.  That's `O(nk)` for the worst case.

Even stopping substring comparisons after the first unequal comparison, while having a smaller coefficient, still is `O(nk)`. Construct a string that's a repetition of many isolated letters, each separated by exactly `k-1` spaces, and search that for an occurrence of k consecutive spaces.  The search will fail, but each substring comparison will take an amortized `k/2` compares to find that out, and you're still at `O(nk)`.

If `k` is known to be much less than `n`, you could treat that as `O(n)`.

The average case depends on the actual algorithm used, and also on the distribution of characters in the two strings; and you haven't said what either of those were.