# Leetcode solution of Check Array Formation Through Concatenation

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have tested both string based and map based implementations of this problem. The first one gives 12ms runtime while the second one gives 1ms with both using almost same space. And the implementation structure of both styles looks same.
So, I want to know why there is a much runtime difference between the two.
Here are both the implementations:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean canFormArray(int[] arr, int[][] pieces) {
        
        // string based
        String str = "";
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            str = str + arr[i] + "#";
        }
        
        for (int i=0; i<pieces.length; i++) {
            String str2 = "";
            for (int j=0; j<pieces[i].length; j++) {
                str2 = str2 + pieces[i][j] + "#";
            }
            if (!str.contains(str2)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
        
        // map based
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            map.put(arr[i], i);
        }
        
        for (int i=0; i<pieces.length; i++) {
            if (!map.containsKey(pieces[i][0])) {
                return false;
            }
            int index = map.get(pieces[i][0]);
            for (int j=1; j<pieces[i].length; j++) {
                if (!map.containsKey(pieces[i][j])) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (map.get(pieces[i][j]) != index+1) {
                    return false;
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: HashMap.get and HashMap.containsKey are all O(1), while String.containsKey is O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

str.contains(str2) has a time complexity of O(nm) in the worst case.

while map.containsKey(pieces[i][0]) has a time complexity of O(1)

Please check this answer as well to find out more details
[Time complexity of String.contains()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391513/time-complexity-of-string-contains/51391945)

Answer (score 0):

At a guess `str = str + arr[i] + "#";` and `str2 = str2 + pieces[i][j] + "#";` is creating new Strings inside a loop. Whilst creating objects is not the heavyweight task it once was, it's still best to avoid doing this in a loop.

To avoid this, create StringBuilder outside your loop, use the `append` method inside the loop and use `toString()` once the loop has completed.

Answer (score 0):

- A similar approach, this'd pass in Java:

```
public class Solution {
    public static final boolean canFormArray(
        final int[] arr,
        final int[][] pieces
    ) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int num : arr) {
            sb.append(num);
            sb.append("#");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

            for (int j = 0; j < pieces[i].length; j++) {
                res.append(String.valueOf(pieces[i][j]));
                res.append("#");
            }

            if (!sb.toString().contains(res.toString())) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

- A better approach is to use a `HashMap`, here is a C++ version:

```
// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>


// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();


struct Solution {
    static const bool canFormArray(
        const std::vector<int>& arr,
        const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& pieces
    ) {
        std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<int>> starts_partitions;

        for (const auto& piece : pieces) {
            starts_partitions[piece[0]] = piece;
        }

        std::vector<int> form_array;

        for (const auto& num : arr) {
            form_array.insert(
                std::end(form_array),
                std::begin(starts_partitions[num]),
                std::end(starts_partitions[num])
            );
        }

        return form_array == arr;
    }

};



// int main() {

//     std::cout <<  Solution().canFormArray({85}, {{85}}) << "\n";
//     std::cout <<  Solution().canFormArray({15, 88}, {{88}, {15}}) << "\n";
//     std::cout <<  Solution().canFormArray({49, 18, 16}, {{16, 18, 49}}) << "\n";
//     std::cout <<  Solution().canFormArray({91, 4, 64, 78}, {{78}, {4, 64}, {91}}) << "\n";
//     std::cout <<  Solution().canFormArray({1, 3, 5, 7}, {{2, 4, 6, 8}}) << "\n";
// };
```

- It would  be easier to understand if we'd just look into the Python version:

```
class Solution:
    def canFormArray(self, arr: List[int], pieces: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
        starts_pieces = {piece[0]: piece for piece in pieces}

        form_array = []

        for num in arr:
            form_array += starts_pieces.get(num, [])

        return form_array == arr
```